# PHP - MYSQL How to make a web page accessible only to few roles?

Tags: php, html, mysql, session, xampp

I need a help from PHP Experts.. I am designing web pages for "Online Recruitment System".

There are almost 3 roles:

1. HR
2. Admin

   - Manual (Apti,Technical,Programming) {Web Pages}
   - Automation (Apti,Technical,Programming 1,Programming 2)
   - Development (Apti,Technical,Programming 1,Programming 2,Programming

3.Candidate

I have created php page with MySQL as backend in XAMPP. But the problem i am facing is Sessions are shared. I have logged in as HR but when i edit the path in browser URL, HR is able to access Admin category pages.

How to categorise the web page which can be accessible only to few roles?

What type of session code should i write? I am new to php so please give a right direction..

Comment: Are you using any php framework? some frameworks has packages for USER ROLES.

Comment: You should not relies on session to identify user roles. A better way is to store only username in it and do a MySQL query to fetch granted roles. Before display of your pages, add a test if username in session have role needed to display the page.

Comment: No Ritchie, I am not using any framework.. Guide me on the framework so that i will try to work on that..

Comment: Camille, i will work on that.

Comment: You may want to check which other features you need, maybe research a little http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/php-frameworks-comparison or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:PHP_frameworks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set another session for stored user role

```
$_SESSION["role"]="HR";
```

or

```
$_SESSION["role"]="ADMIN";
```

the top of the page HR or ADMIN page

```
if($_SESSION["role"]!='HR')
{
//redirect to common page
}
```

same as admin

Answer (score 0):

Create the following tables

1. roles

   - id, name, description
   - 1, admin, ur description...
2. permissions

   - id, key
   - 1, edit_post
3. linkage

   - id, role_id, permission_id
   - 1, 1      , 1

On your user table add a field to store user role_id.
Create a function to check for permissions linked to user role_id and store permissions liked to user role_id in an array
ie select * from linkage where role_id = "your user role id" and loop through results or use join statement to get permission key

```
$arrayRolePermission = [];
```

On your we pages you call your function to check if user has a specific role. for example

```
$user_role_id = you store this on your session

if(user_can('edit_post',$user_role_id))
{
    echo "Access Allowed";
}
else 
{
    echo "Access dinied";
}
```